# How to keep GCM in sync with app and server?

Tags: android, asynchronous, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM for app notifications as illustrated [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).  The code is boilerplate:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
}
```

Then the `onRegistered()` callback updates my server with the returned registration id.

However, on several occasions GCM has gotten into an inconsistent state.  In one case, it doesn't forward any notifications even though `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId()` gives me a non-empty registration id string.  In other cases, I end up getting two or more duplicate messages.

In attempt to avoid these situations, I currently have a brute force solution that works like this:

```
if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this))
    GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
else
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, GCMConstants.SENDER_ID);
```

In the onUnregistered() callback, I tell my server to delete the registration id, and then call `GCMRegistrar.register()`.  In the `onRegistered()` callback, I tell my server to add the registration id back.

So far, it's working, but it's obviously less efficient than the way this is supposed to work, and I don't know for sure if it's immune to the inconsistency problems.  It would be better if I could count on `getRegistrationId()` to always return a valid id, i.e., the current/canonical registration id.

**What's the simplest/cleanest way to ensure consistency between my app, my server, and GCM?**  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of getting duplicate messages can be solved if you parse the response you get from Google, and identify the situation where you receive a canonical registration id in the response. In this case you can delete the old registration id, and keep the canonical one instead.

I think a better solution than your brute force solution is to always call `register` when the app is launched. You may receive in `onRegistered()` the same registration ID you got on the previous call, but if you persist that registration id in your device, you can compare the persisted ID to the received ID and avoid re-sending the registration ID to your server if it didn't change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - a quick follow up.  What is the use/effectiveness of the `getRegistrationId()` function?  I'm not clear where it gets the reg id from; it appears to be a synchronous call so I guess it's not coming from GCM directly.  One of my problems was that it was occasionally returning a stale token (?).  Am I right that it isn't necessary in your solution?

Comment: One more question.  Is it safe to call GCM's `register()` multiple times?  If it returns a different reg id, then what happens to the old one?

Comment: I never use `getRegistrationId()` so I can't say. It would be interesting to try calling that method after you `register` and `unregister`. I wonder if it would still return the old id. Perhaps it only returns null before the first registration ever. I think it should be safe to call `register` multiple times.  If it returns a different reg id, the old one will still work, but when you send a notification using the old one, you'll get in the response the new reg id as canonical registration id. But you should delete the old one from your DB once you get a new one.

Comment: BTW, I don't use the `register` method either. I use the code that creates a `registrationIntent` and starts a service. You can find that code [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) (4 lines of code in `Registering for GCM` section). I guess it does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll experiment with your suggestions.  In the end I may stick with the brute force solution simply because keeping everything in sync is super important for this app, and this approach seems to give the strongest guarantee of that (at the expense of a little performance).